# MySQL - Many UPDATEs to run after INSERT

Tags: mysql, php

I have a basic CRUD application where people are adding records. When they `INSERT` someone new, there are many updates (about 100) that need to be done to the record after it's been added.

I have tried to put the `UPDATE` statements in a `TRIGGER` but it would either lock the table --OR-- give me the "can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger" error.

Then I tried to put them all in a `PROCEDURE` -- which took about 30 seconds to run. Unacceptable.

I don't think I'm doing anything difficult here. Mostly, the updates are updating one field based on another.

Example

```
INSERT INTO data_table (field1, field2, ...) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', ...);
```

Then the updates:

```
UPDATE data_table SET field2 = 'New York City' WHERE field1 = '212';
UPDATE data_table SET field2 = 'Los Angeles' WHERE field1 = '213';
```

etc.

Would it be faster/more efficient to do a bunch of `IF...THEN` statements in PHP to change the variable before inserting?

I'm just trying to speed up the process of inserting the record and processing the updates. Any help?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas , 100 update in same tables or different tables  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose that you have built a reference data set that has two (or more) fields.  For the sake of argument lets call the table geography

- Area_Code
- City

The MySQL update syntax would be

```
UPDATE data_table, geography
SET data_table.field2 = geography.City
WHERE data_table.field1 = geography.Area_Code
```

Potential pitfalls to watch out for are the data types, size and collation discrepancies between data_table.field1 and geography.Area_Code.

If geography.Area_Code is unique and must always be present make sure you stick a primary key on it.

It is probably worth  adding an index to data_table.field1.  Again, if it is mandatory and unique make it a primary key.

Comment: Yes (in this example) the Area_Code is unique. I made it a Primary Key and re-wrote the statements like you suggested. 30 seconds down to 3! More than acceptable.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas - 3 is unacceptable for a trivial update.  What indexes do you have on the tables?  Are there 99 more updates?